# project xxx: GWT Module yyy not found in project sources or resources

Tags: maven, gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

I am seeing some random failure in our multi-module gwt app.

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.6.1:compile (compile) on project
>   xxx: GWT Module yyy not found in project sources or resources. ->
>   [Help 1] 2015-08-18 09:26:34 gobuilds.Compile :
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.6.1:compile
>   (compile) on project xxx: GWT Module yyy not found in project sources
>   or resources. 2015-08-18 09:26:34 gobuilds.Compile :  at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
>   2015-08-18 09:26:34 gobuilds.Compile :    at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>   2015-08-18 09:26:34 gobuilds.Compile :    at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>   2015-08-18 09:26:34 gobuilds.Compile :    at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>   2015-08-18 09:26:34 gobuilds.Compile :    at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:189)
>   2015-08-18 09:26:34 gobuilds.Compile :    at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:185)
>   2015-08-18 09:26:34 gobuilds.Compile :    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) 2015-08-18
>   09:26:34 gobuilds.Compile :   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>   2015-08-18 09:26:34 gobuilds.Compile :    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) 2015-08-18
>   09:26:34 gobuilds.Compile :   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   2015-08-18 09:26:34 gobuilds.Compile :    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   2015-08-18 09:26:34 gobuilds.Compile :    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

We are using:

> GWT - 2.6.1 GWT Maven Plugin - 2.6.1

GWT maven args:

> -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx1024m -Djava.io.tmpdir=${project.build.directory} -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing

We are using maven parallel build option with:

> -T 2

Interesting thing is 'xxx' is constant and 'yyy' may be different in each run. However, the failure is totally sporadic.

The problem is very hard to reproduce and hence wanted to ask if anyone had some ideas around this?

Comment: I have never tried parallel builds so no idea; but if you run with debug logs (`-X`) the plugin will print the classpath being used so you can maybe have an idea of where it comes from.

Comment: The problem is this happens on our build systems and putting -X flag there for all the build will be quite intrusive. I am not able to reproduce this locally.

Comment: The only other option I can think of is to audit the plugin's code…